# JSONP not working with gravatar

Tags: jquery, gravatar

In my app, I am trying to fetch a user's profile from gravatar during registration, so that he does not have to enter his First, Last name. I am using the code below -

```
    $.ajax({
                url: "http://www.gravatar.com/" + get_gravatar_url(email) + ".json",
                async: false,       
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                crossDomain: true,
                success: function(data){
                    console.log('data = ' + gravatar_profile);
                    data_received = 1;
                },
                error: function() {
                    console.log('oh noes!');
                },
        });
```

When the user's email is not found, I get this error in my console -

```
GET http://en.gravatar.com/79ac7efbf9deb9b7f7965d9aa564078b.json?callback=jQuery191009235964552499354_1373008918711 404 (Not Found)
```

But, the error function does not get called. ( can someone explain why ? )
However, if the user's email is found, the success function does get called.

I also tried [jquery-jsonp](https://github.com/jaubourg/jquery-jsonp), with the following function -

```
$.jsonp({
            async: false,
            url: "http://www.gravatar.com/" + get_gravatar_url(email) + ".json",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            crossDomain: true,
            timeout: 5000,
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function(XHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                alert("ERREUR: " + textStatus);
                //alert("ERREUR: " + errorThrown);
            },
        });
```

While the 404 error is still displayed in the console, at least it detects it and shows the alert. But, as gravatar sends data in json format, I get a new error -

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

Please can anyone show how to make this work ?

Comment: In this `success: function(data){
                alert(data);
            }` what is the value of `data` here?

Comment: the data is the user profile returned by gravatar. It's a json object.
You can view it here (http://en.gravatar.com/e713234820d52a59d34a0a05225c047e.json)

Comment: You can also use this [Remote JSON](http://bob.ippoli.to/archives/2005/12/05/remote-json-jsonp/)

Answer (score 0):

For your reference here i posted a simple JSONP example procedure.

```
 OTPrequest = function(){
    customerObj = {'data':'abc'}
    $.ajax({
      type:'GET',
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      data: customerObj,
      jsonpCallback: 'loadit',
      url: 'http://abc/retrieve',
      success: function (responseData) { //Your server responseData should be like this "loadit('otp sent')"
        loadit(responseData)
      },
      error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
        //Error handler.
      }
    });
    function loadit(data){
      console.log(data);
      alert(data); //This will alert the popup as "opt sent".
    }
  }
```

Comment: @ParinPorecha: 1)Cross-domain request won't possible without JSONP. 2) What error/issue are you facing now with this code? Kindly refer this too [JSONP concept](http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/).

Comment: it's not working. Is there any way to request json cross-domain without using dataType: 'jsonp' ?

Comment: I'm getting the same error as before - `GET http://en.gravatar.com/79ac7efbf9deb9b7f7965d9aa564078b.json?callback=jQuery191009235964552499354_1373008918711 404 (Not Found)`

Plus, `async: false` does not seem to be working too ( due to the error, not due to your code )

Comment: The url is fine. Opening it via the browser works perfectly well.